# Does Windows DNS Server 2008 support RTT?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns

Does the Windows DNS server support RTT when used for recursive dns queries?

Answer (score 1):

No RTT is not considered.  See [Using Forwarders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754931.aspx)

Comment: So thats for forwarders, but it does not say for the other setups where it does recursive queries. This documents states it does: http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/dns+windows+server/Chapter+2.+How+Does+DNS+Work/2.6+Resolution/  but cannot find it anywhere on microsoft.com

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. 2003 does so I would guess that 2008 does as well this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772774(WS.10).aspx is for 2003 that mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out they do support RTT - but hardcoded to 100ms (go figure)